# Reading local binary file on Playbook through HTML5

Tags: blackberry-webworks, blackberry-playbook

I'm making a MP3 player for Blackberry Playbook in HTML5 and I need to know how to read local binary file without using  tag (like in XHR).

Is there any way? Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
blackberry.io.file.readFile("/path/to/MP3File",
          function(fullPath,blobData){

                doSomethingWithMP3(blobData);

          },
          {async : false});
```

You can find information on the WebWorks APIs at: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis

More info on the readFile function is here: [https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.io.file.html#.readFile](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.io.file.html#.readFileahttps://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.io.file.html#.readFile)